# Letters / text that I type shows up in the wrong order

Tags: keyboard, imac, text

I've been having this issue for a while now, very inconsistently.
When I type strands of text, sometimes the letters appears in the wrong order (I remember it mostly happening when I type text in Safari).
One example:

[image]

***I typed "Install Canon Printer".***

I am using an iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) running 10.10.5, with this keyboard:

[image]

They keyboard is plugged directly into the iMac (no hub).

<sub>Note: Sometimes I type things wrong, but AFAIK I'm not dyslexic.</sub>

Comment: Are the letters appearing one by one in the wrong order, or is what you are typing being autocorrected by the app or os?  Check Edit > Spelling and Grammar and make sure "correct spelling automatically" is off and see if it still happens.  Though it hardly seems like autocorrect would generate the example you show....

Comment: There's actually a lag in them appearing. Like they appear by bulk. I'm thinking it has to do with packs of data being sent to the computer through USB and arriving in the wrong order but I can't explain... Hardware is in excellent condition. "Correct spelling automatically" is OFF.

Comment: It would be helpfui if you could try another keyboard and see if the same thing occurs with that, either usb or bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks, I have another bluetooth keyboard, I'll try that for a while and get back here

Comment: It also happens to me!
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), laptop's keyboard, MacOS 10.13.2.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me, especially at times when CPU usage is otherwise high. I've got a Matias backlit bluetooth keyboard running on Mac OS X 10.13.4. This has been happening for a few OS versions now. If this is a buffer/prioritization issue, it's possible the bluetooth bus/controller is suffering from the same issue as the USB bus/controller.

I find shutting down all high-CPU apps gets the keyboard working reliably again, though this is a method for clue gathering rather than a fix – I need to be able to type no matter what!

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible to set up a watchdog to interrupt other processes in deference to the USB or Bluetooth buffer? That would solve the issue if this is indeed down to resource overuse.

Comment: Thanks @RickGladwin ! I agree with you that it looks like the computer is processing information for a bit, and sometimes spewing out letters already typed all of a sudden, garbled. I’ve also seen it happen on slower iPhones, actually...

Comment: As of 2020/10/25, I am still having this issue, albeit on totally different equipment (MacBook Pro 2020). I will type something, say in a Facebook Messenger window, the text will not appear instantly, sometimes I will even have a beach ball pointer for a few seconds, then the text gets inserted into the chat window, garbled.